# In Haxe hxml file, how to target main class not in the root package

Tags: compiler-errors, haxe, hxml

I'm trying to compile a project where the main entry point isn't in the root package (which virtually all examples use, e.g. `-main Main`), but I keep getting this error message:

```
Error: Invalid commandline class : rtp.qt.QTPrinter should be QTPrinter
```

Here are the various syntaxes that should work:

```
-cp src
-main rtp.qt.QTPrinter
```

Or:

```
-cp src
-main rtp/qt/QTPrinter.hx
```

Answer (score 2):

It turns out, those syntaxes are both fine. I had just moved the `QTPrinter.hx` file from `src/` to `src/rtp/qt/` directory and I **forgot to update the package statement** at the top of the file (hence the invalid commandline class error.)

In my `src/rtp/qt/QTPrinter.hx` file, fix the package statement:

```
package rtp.qt;
```

I'm posting this mistake in hopes it helps someone. Cheers!

Comment: I literally made the same mistake (with a different file) just yesterday - happens to the best of us!