# Can't build Haxe source file

Tags: haxe

I tried haxe on MacOS, and setup the toolchain correctly, etc., but when i tried to compile a file, i got an error, so i tried again with an example in the tutorial (here: https://haxe.org/documentation/introduction/language-introduction.html),
and got the same error, which is:

```
Type not found : HelloWorld
```

for the command:

```
haxe -main HelloWorld -js HelloWorld.js
```

to compile the file:

```
class HelloWorld {
    static public function main() {
      trace("Hello World");
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: This could happen if the file isn't named HelloWorld.hx or if your terminal isn't in the directory with the haxe file (you would need to `cd` into it).

Comment: FYI, you can pass `-main` a fully qualified class name, or a filename (related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35952115). And while that's fine for a quick test, long term you're probably better off explicitly specifying your class path(s) with `-cp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your haxe source file is named as `HelloWorld.hx` and your working directory is at where the source file is, when you run the compile command

Comment: So the name of the main class must be the same as the name of the file?

Comment: For starters, your filename should always be same as the class name. But you can actually put more than on class in a single file. Check out the Module section in the manual: https://haxe.org/manual/type-system-modules-and-paths.html